# Retrieve max of column using reflected table in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

The problem is quite simply explained. You have a DB, you have a table and you have an attribute.
What you want to do is to connect to the database, query the table for the max on the content of the table of a specific attribute.

What I tried so far is:

```
attr_name = 'foo'
meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=self._engine)
obj_table = meta.tables[table_name]

print("<< select max(attr_name) from obj_table >>")
```

What I would like to do is to print out the max. I tried with sessions, with getattr.. no clue. I just want to get the max out of this table, from a column having a name passed by parameter (I can't use dot notation).

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from sqlalchemy import select, func

col = getattr(obj_table.c, attr_name)
q = select([func.max(col)], obj_table)
with self._engine.connect() as conn:
    res = conn.execute(q)
    max_value = res.fetchone()[0]
```

The important thing here is that table columns are accessed via `obj_table.c` (or `obj_table.columns`).